# Shall I create resolver for each query or for all of its fields in GraphQL?

Tags: go, graphql

I'm interested in using GraphQL and I've just started experimenting with it.

In a GraphQL [tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-the-schema-ac5e2950214e), one can see the following quote:

> Each field in a GraphQL schema is backed by a resolver.

But if you look at [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) (which is a golang library for building GraphQL servers) [todo example](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/blob/master/example/todo/todo.go) that uses the following schema:

```
...
type MyQuery {
    todo(id: ID!): Todo
    lastTodo: Todo
    todos: [Todo!]!
}

type MyMutation {
    createTodo(todo: TodoInput!): Todo!
    updateTodo(id: ID!, changes: Map!): Todo
}

type Todo {
    id: ID!
    text: String!
    done: Boolean!
}
...
```

it actually uses 3 autogenerated resolvers (i.e., 1 for each *query*, not a field):

```
func (r *QueryResolver) Todo(ctx context.Context, id int) (*Todo, error) {
func (r *QueryResolver) LastTodo(ctx context.Context) (*Todo, error) {
func (r *QueryResolver) Todos(ctx context.Context) ([]*Todo, error) {
```

Is it the expected behavior not to autogenerate resolvers for each field (but for each query instead)?

Comment: That looks like one resolver for each field in the `MyQuery` type, which happens to be the top-level query type (but otherwise is an ordinary GraphQL object type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When entire type is backed by a resolver then it's still true that each field is backed by resolver ;)

Comparing to SQL - usually you don't ask for each (single) field separately when you want entire record/row.

Field level resolvers are needed when type resolver don't return data for all required (by query) fields - f.e. for relations.

Comment: I'll be happy with an example in any programming language (want to see the types with relations & required fields). BTW is it correct that if I create a relationship between 2 types: i.e., _todo_ contains _task_ then I'd expect a separate autogenerated resolver for a task?

Comment: In the lib you're using ... [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen#how-do-i-prevent-fetching-child-objects-that-might-not-be-used) - you have `friends` - field for relation with separate resolver

Comment: And how does it work for 2 resolvers under the hood in `gqlgen`? I.e., if there's `users.friends` field and `allUsers` query, will `users_resolver` init all fields but `.friends` and then `friends` will be resolved separately by its resolver? I don't really get the workflow since `allUsers` returns `[Users]` and we can't init `users.friends` field.

Comment: 'engine' tries to collect required data for all fields - additional resolvers are used for each object (`User`) and each field/property (undefined at start) not resolved by type resolver (on each level, top-down) - returns null for not resolved fields (no field resolver, no matching data etc)